# How to fix onclick in a loop?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to loop an HTMLCollection and i want to add a onclick event inside each element.

```
for(var page of pages){
   page.onclick = () => {
       console.log(count)
   }
   count += 1
}
```

Well, the problem is actually that when i click the button, it shows up only the last counted number (5), but not actually the counted element. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: move `count += 1` inside the onclick handler

Comment: i can't because i want to increment other stuffs on in the onclick function

Comment: For the question to be complete, it should have desired/expected output in addition to actual output. What is `count` supposed to represent? The index of `page` in `pages`?

Comment: Avoid the `onclick` property. For this specific use case, `((count) => page.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(count))(count);` can be used instead of `page.onclick = () => { console.log(count) }`. But what do you need `count` for? There’s very likely a much better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a for Loop.

```js
for (let count = 0; count < pages.length; count++) {
   pages[count].onclick = () => {
       console.log(count)
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var page of pages){
   page.onclick = () => {
       console.log(count++)
   }
}
```

I guess this is what you want ? increment after a click ? and not in the for loop

Comment: Ok, and how could i access to the page element?

Comment: in the page element

Comment: @Diaskyyy you can add an argument event inside the function like this ```    page.onclick = (event) => {
       console.log(count++, event)
   }```

event will have a lot of data that you may want about the event (click) but also on the element clicked